# Regex to remove ALL single characters from a string

Tags: php, regex

I need a Regular Expression to remove ALL single characters from a string, not just single letters or numbers

The string is:

> "A Future Ft Casino Karate Chop ( Prod By Metro )"

it should come out as:

> "Future Ft Casino Karate Chop Prod By Metro"

The expression I am using at the moment (in PHP), correctly removes the single 'A' but leaves the single '(' and ')'

This is the code I am using:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b\w\b\s?/', '', $string);
```

Comment: To explain: `\b` will only match between something matching `\w` and something matching `\W`. Since `<space>` and `(` match `\W`, there's no boundary between them.Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick replies and explanations. In summary `$string = preg_replace('/(^| ).( |$)/', '$1', $string);` works perfectly for what I need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
(^| ).( |$)
```

Breakdown:

```
   1.  (^| )  ->  Beginning of line or space  
   2.  .      ->  Any character  
   3.  ( |$)  ->  Space or End of line
```

Actual code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(^| ).( |$)/', '$1', $string);
```

Note: I'm not familiar with the workings of PHP regex, so the code might need a slight tweak depending on how the actual regex needs declared.

As m.buettner pointed out, there will be a trailing white space here with this code.  A trim would be needed to clear it out.

Edit: Arnis Juraga pointed out that this would not clear out multiple single characters `a b c` would filter out to `b`. If this is an issues use this regex:

```
(^| ).(( ).)*( |$)
```

The `(( ).)*` added to the middle will look for any space following by any character 0 or more times. The downside is this will end up with double spaces where a series of single characters were located.

Meaning this:

```
The a b c dog
```

Will become this:

```
The  dog
```

After performing the replacement to get single individual characters, you would need to use the following regex to locate the double spaces, then replace with a single space

```
( ){2}
```

Comment: @Daedalus thanks for your comment in my question. Didn't understand the question exactly - answer withdrawn.

Comment: Very close! Produces `code`Future Ft Casino Karate ChopProd By Metro`code`Should be:<br /><br />Future Ft Casino Karate Chop Prod By Metro

Comment: @user1810833 what is still missing? Why only close?

Comment: A-Za-z0-9 instead of a dot :)

Comment: @AyeshK Then it wouldn't remove the `(` or the `)`, he said any character, specifically not just any letter or number.

Comment: @user1810833 Simply placing `$1$2` or `$1` in your replacement parameter should fix that easily.

Comment: Hi, sorry I ran out of time trying to edit my comment in to a more readable format! `$tags = preg_replace('/(^| ).( |$)/', '$1', $tags);` works like a charm - many thanks!! :-)

Comment: @Nick +1, nice and simple answer. You should probably mention the caveat though, that this will leave a trailing whitespace, if the last character is a single character.

Comment: @m.buettner I added the note pointing out the whitespace. Thank you for the input, I didn't even think about that last whitespace.

Comment: This will not remove sequential single characters, e.g.: "a b c" will be transformed to "b"

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more efficient version that does not require capturing would be using lookarounds. It's a bit less intuitive due to the multiple negative logic:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!\S).(?!\S)\s*/', '', $input);
```

This will remove any character that is **neither** preceded **nor** followed by a **non**-whitespace character (so only those that are between whitespace or at the string boundaries). It will also include all trailing whitespace in the match, so as to leave only the preceding whitespace if there is any. The caveat is, that just like Nick's answer the `)` at the end of the string will leave a trailing whitespace (because it is in front of the character). This can easily be solved by `trim`ming the string.